# Multiple SyncAdapter to Same Service?

Tags: android, asynchronous, service

In the Google info, it says that the service exists to perform a sync once requested by the adapter. If this is the case, would it be possible to do this with multiple adapters? If so, then how?

I imagine that there could be something like a command pattern where all adapters are given a SyncAdapterInterface and then we have a reference to the manager that manages all these adapters. However, the only control as to which adapter gets activated would be through the intent in onBind.

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's a 1:1 relationship between all of the sync components so you can't have multiple services/SyncAdapters bound to the same content authority. However, there's no reason that you can't call multiple disparate components in your `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter`'s [onPerformSync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html#onPerformSync(android.accounts.Account,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentProviderClient,%20android.content.SyncResult)). Do note that the `onPerformSync` method does run on a separate thread and calls should be done synchronously (as the system only holds a wakelock for you while `onPerformSync` is running) which precludes starting other services.

Comment: Clear and concise. Thanks!